# Avoid wrong interpretation of source with document.createElement for dynamic sources

Tags: javascript

I have script that I would like visitors on my website to run when they load a web page. It looks like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var pxl=document.createElement('img');
    pxl.setAttribute('src', 'http://localhost:8080/getTrackingPixel')
    document.body.appendChild(pxl);
}
```

Most of the times the source returns an image and it works fine. However, sometimes it returns this:

```
 <html><body style="background-color:transparent"></body></html>
```

And I can't really change the fact that it might sometimes not return an image. How do I change the javascript so that it can handle the html response without any errors? It might be possible for me to predict when it happens though - but I haven't managed to find a good way to request the source and return the html either.

Comment: `document.createElement` never returns a string, so that's not really possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using the javascript `Image` object which, unlike the `createElement` approach, allows you to fetch the src url *before* inserting the img in the DOM.

The `onload` event of the `Image` object won't fire if the loaded content isn't an img.

Here it is :

```
window.onload = function(){
    var pxl = new Image();
    pxl.onload = function(){
        // is IMG
        document.body.appendChild(pxl);
    }
    pxl.onerror = function(){
        // is not IMG
        // Meaning in your case : <html><body style="background-color:transparent"></body></html>
    }
    pxl.src = 'http://localhost:8080/getTrackingPixel';
}
```

(Note that your code also missed the `semicolon ";"` line 4)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question to the fullest! That did it for me :)